# FaceTime “poor connection” never resumes

Tags: facetime

I FaceTime every other week or so with my parents. We talk for 1-4 hours when we do. Most times, 1 to 3 times throughout the call, the image will freeze, go blurry, and give me the error “Poor Connection, the video will resume automatically when the connection improves” but the video never resumes, even though if I hang up and call back, the video is fine. Is there a way to fix this so that I don’t have to hang up and call back to get the video back?

I usually use a MacBook Air, but it also happens on my iPhone 6s. My parents are usually using either an iPhone 6s Plus or an iPhone 7.

Comment: Specific iPhone models aren't the problem here - it can be interference with the WiFi signal strength from the equipment you're both connected to that causes the loss of sync. This interference can be from any number of sources, including microwave ovens; Direct Satellite Service (DSS); Power sources; 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz phones; Wireless RF video. See this page at [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201542) for more detail. If you are connecting with cell, or a mix of cell on one end and WiFi on the other, there could be any number of cell service related glitches. Hard to tell.

Comment: Yeah. Could be any number of things. But I’m just wanting to know if there’s a way to make it resume without hanging up and calling back.

Comment: In my experience, starting a new session is the only way to get it to re-sync.

Comment: So it sounds like what you’re saying is that the error message is inaccurate. It’s not that the connection is temporarily poor (e.g. slow) and can resume when the speed picks up. It’s that there’s some sort of irreconcilable unsynchronized state that the app communication gets into. What is this conclusion based on?

Comment: Just personal experience, hepcat. Recent example: last week I was using FT with my brother over a public wifi at a rehabilitation center where my mom was recovering from surgery. After two drop outs, I turned off WiFi and used the 3-bar LTE cell service for the rest of the 'visit' without a glitch. There are so many variables on both ends, it is hard to pinpoint a specific problem. It's worth experimenting to find the best connection type.

Comment: My parents have poor cell service in their house, so unfortunately, the only option is WiFi. Your theory about synching might be the case. Regardless, whichever the reason for the video interruption, FT is designed to be fault tolerant in that it claims it has the ability to detect a resolution of an issue and resume the video automatically. I think it’s likely that there’s either a bug in the resolution detection or in the code that reinitializes the video stream. My hope is that it’s the former and that someone knows a trick to force it to try to resume the video stream.

Comment: I have this same problem FaceTiming with my brother. His router is one floor above him. Making sure he was on 5 Ghz band seems to have resolved it, despite him having a repeater setup in his basement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’ll have them check next time. But still, if reinitiating the call is a temporary fix, it should be able to resume on its own (in theory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that sometime after I posted this question, Apple resolved the issue with the ability to resume the connection in the case of my MacBook Air and my parents' iPhone 6 & 7, but I only know this because of the same issue recurring in a very specific case:

A few months after the pandemic started, I had set up a FaceTime Portal with my parents between 2 dedicated devices: my iPad Mini and their iPad Air (1 or 2, maxed out at iOS 12.5).

For 3 weeks, it worked great. I ran it every weekday for the whole work day (8 hours per day). I was initially running iPadOS 13.7, and after 3 weeks, I updated to 14.x. Immediately after updating, the problem described in my question started happening consistently every time within a minute or 2 of placing the call.

Calls would barely last a minute before I would see a burry darkened background with a "poor connection" warning. Maybe 10 seconds after that, I would without fail, get a call failed error.

I immediately reached out to Apple. They told me that there was a bug. Initially they told me to watch for an update of iOS 12.5, but ultimately, the problem must have been server-side, because after a few months, it just suddenly started working reliably.

There had been a 12.5.1 update that I had my parents install during that time, but multiple tests after that update showed the problem persisted. I had also updated my iPad Mini to 14.4, and again, the problem persisted.

Then one day, I randomly tested it, as I occasionally did, and it stayed connected all day. I still occasionally get the poor connection message, but it almost always comes back. Nothing changed on my side.

So the answer to this question is, the only thing you can do is call Apple and complain. My feedback carried weight because I had been using FaceTime 8h/day for 3 weeks and they could see it in the logs they requested and they could also see all of the failed calls after the 14 update. Plus, we were each using Airport Extremes for our WiFi connections.